# Resizable Element in Angular causes highlighted text. How to prevent?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am currently working on a site where I provide code generators. There I have a split screen. Left is the generator, right is the screen. The users should be able to resize the width of the screen themselves. Therefore I use angular-resizable-element (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resizable-element). I develop this page with Angular7.

**Problem:** 
When I resize the part of the screen in Safari, the browser automatically highlights large parts of the text. How can I stop this?

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/how-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting. It might be an option for you to disable text selection completely or only disable it while resizing.

Comment: Works well. Thanks!